# 'this' is Undefined in TypeScript Property Decorator

Tags: javascript, typescript, properties, this, decorator

I'm trying to understand TypeScript decorators (specifically for properties), and I came up with the following code based on some examples I've seen:

*decorator.ts*

```
export function logProperty(target: any, key: string) {

  let val = this[key];

  const getter = () => {
    console.log(`Get: ${key} => ${val}`);
    return val;
  };

  const setter = (newVal) => {
    console.log(`Set: ${key} => ${newVal}`);
    val = newVal;
  };

  if (delete this[key]) {
    Object.defineProperty(target, key, {
      get: getter,
      set: setter,
      enumerable: true,
      configurable: true
    });
  }
}
```

*main.ts*

```
import { logProperty } from './decorators';

class Person {
  @logProperty
  firstName: string;

  @logProperty
  lastName: string;

  constructor(firstName: string, lastName: string) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }
}

const foo = new Person('Foo', 'Bar');
```

My problem is that when I try to run this, I get:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined

It seems that the value of `this` is undefined. What am I missing?

For reference, my `tsconfig.json` has:

```
"target": "es5"
"experimentalDecorators": true
"strict": false
```

**UPDATE 8/27**
It seems that this issue only arises when the decorator is in a different `.ts` file. If you place the decorator in a different file and import it from another file, then the error occurs. However, placing them all in the same file doesn't cause the issue. Am I simply misunderstanding how `this` gets interpreted?

Comment: In what line do you get the error?

Comment: The first time `this` is referenced, so the third line down.

Comment: Strange, works fine on my side and also in [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html)

Comment: Thanks @AlekseyL.. It seems to be working in the playground for me too. The problem is that I'm running my code in a project setup as a node module, so there's something that is different between the two, just can't figure out what...  You can try pasting the code into a file (or create a new file) from [this repo](https://github.com/menehune23/local-motive) to reproduce the error.

Comment: @AlekseyL. I've added an update to the original question. I also updated the code examples to reflect the separate files. Do you have any insights?

Comment: You're right. Investigated this a bit - provided code for property decorator is not usable. `this` not refers to instance. It works in playground only because `this` refers to `window`

Comment: Ok, well maybe `this` is not intended to be used within the decorator? It's weird that many examples do it, but that doesn't mean it's correct I guess...

Comment: At least not in decorator function body, because decorator code runs before instance is created. What is your use case, what would you like to do with property decorator?

Comment: Essentially, I'd like to use it to associate a path with nested field values. For example `model.field1.fieldA` might be an integer, and it's path resolves to `'model/field1/fieldA'` (see [this repo](https://github.com/menehune23/local-motive) for a better idea).

Comment: I am running into this exact same issue, however my logProperty decorator is defined in the same file. `this` is undefined however. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr:** I'm not sure why OP's config didn't work; it seems to work beautifully now. See below for some brute-force testing.

### Guess

I'm wondering if you were somehow picking up the wrong `tsconfig`. I've looked at [your repo's `tsconfig`](https://github.com/menehune23/local-motive/blob/eb3f2097bd00b63fa7a7e4ad1c03714da0c2e2e2/tsconfig.json) and it looks correct. Is there any chance another config file was infecting those runs? I see [there were no automated tests there](https://github.com/menehune23/local-motive/blob/eb3f2097bd00b63fa7a7e4ad1c03714da0c2e2e2/.travis.yml).

### Testing

I ran into a similar issue today and threw together [a quick test](https://github.com/thecjharries/typescript-strict-demo) using OP as a blueprint. I pulled compiler options [from the official docs](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/66bdbe15f146b242eac5dcec9bff366622aa6acb/pages/Compiler%20Options.md).

#### `decorators.ts`

```
export function logProperty(target: any, key: string) {

    let val = this[key];

    const getter = () => {
        console.log(`Get: ${key} => ${val}`);
        return val;
    };

    const setter = (newVal) => {
        console.log(`Set: ${key} => ${newVal}`);
        val = newVal;
    };

    if (delete this[key]) {
        Object.defineProperty(target, key, {
            get: getter,
            set: setter,
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: true
        });
    }
}
```

#### `main.ts`

```
import { logProperty } from './decorators';

class Person {
    @logProperty
    firstName: string;

    @logProperty
    lastName: string;

    constructor(firstName: string, lastName: string) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}

const foo = new Person('Foo', 'Bar');

function logProperty2(target: any, key: string) {

    let val = this[key];

    const getter = () => {
        console.log(`Get: ${key} => ${val}`);
        return val;
    };

    const setter = (newVal) => {
        console.log(`Set: ${key} => ${newVal}`);
        val = newVal;
    };

    if (delete this[key]) {
        Object.defineProperty(target, key, {
            get: getter,
            set: setter,
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: true
        });
    }
}

class Person2 {
    @logProperty2
    firstName: string;

    @logProperty2
    lastName: string;

    constructor(firstName: string, lastName: string) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}

const foo2 = new Person2('Foo', 'Bar');
```

#### `index.ts`

```
import * as assert from "assert";
import * as shelljs from "shelljs";

const MODULE_GENERATION = [
    "CommonJS",
    "AMD",
    "System",
    "UMD",
    "ES6",
    "ES2015",
    "ESNext",
];

const TARGETS = [
    "ES5",
    "ES2015",
    "ES2016",
    "ES2017"
]

shelljs.exec("tsc --target 'ES5' --module 'None' --strict main.ts", { silent: true });
assert.ok(shelljs.error());
shelljs.exec("tsc --target 'ES5' --module 'None' main.ts", { silent: true });
assert.ok(shelljs.error());

for (const moduleGeneration of MODULE_GENERATION) {
    console.log(`Testing module generation: ${moduleGeneration}`);
    for (const target of TARGETS) {
        console.log(`  Building for ${target}`);
        for (const strict of [true, false]) {
            console.log(`    Strict mode: ${strict ? 'en' : 'dis'}abled`)
            const command = (
                `tsc` +
                ` --module '${moduleGeneration}'` +
                ` --experimentalDecorators` +
                ` --target '${target}'` +
                ` ${strict ? "--strict" : ""}` +
                ` main.ts`
            );
            const output = shelljs.exec(
                command,
                { silent: true },
            );
            let symbol;
            if (strict) {
                assert.ok(shelljs.error());
                symbol = '✖'
            } else {
                assert.strictEqual(0, output.code);
                symbol = '✓'
            }
            console.log(`      ${symbol} ${command}`);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Results

You can see the full build [on Travis](https://travis-ci.org/thecjharries/typescript-strict-demo).

```
Testing module generation: CommonJS
  Building for ES5
    Strict mode: enabled
      ✖ tsc --module 'CommonJS' --experimentalDecorators --target 'ES5' --strict main.ts
    Strict mode: disabled
      ✓ tsc --module 'CommonJS' --experimentalDecorators --target 'ES5'  main.ts
  Building for ES2015
    Strict mode: enabled
      ✖ tsc --module 'CommonJS' --experimentalDecorators --target 'ES2015' --strict main.ts
    Strict mode: disabled
      ✓ tsc --module 'CommonJS' --experimentalDecorators --target 'ES2015'  main.ts
  Building for ES2016
    Strict mode: enabled
      ✖ tsc --module 'CommonJS' --experimentalDecorators --target 'ES2016' --strict main.ts
    Strict mode: disabled
      ✓ tsc --module 'CommonJS' --experimentalDecorators --target 'ES2016'  main.ts
  Building for ES2017
    Strict mode: enabled
      ✖ tsc --module 'CommonJS' --experimentalDecorators --target 'ES2017' --strict main.ts
    Strict mode: disabled
      ✓ tsc --module 'CommonJS' --experimentalDecorators --target 'ES2017'  main.ts
Testing module generation: AMD
  Building for ES5
    Strict mode: enabled
      ✖ tsc --module 'AMD' --experimentalDecorators --target 'ES5' --strict main.ts
    Strict mode: disabled
      ✓ tsc --module 'AMD' --experimentalDecorators --target 'ES5'  main.ts
  Building for ES2015
    Strict mode: enabled
      ✖ tsc --module 'AMD' --experimentalDecorators --target 'ES2015' --strict main.ts
    Strict mode: disabled
      ✓ tsc --module 'AMD' --experimentalDecorators --target 'ES2015'  main.ts
  Building for ES2016
    Strict mode: enabled
      ✖ tsc --module 'AMD' --experimentalDecorators --target 'ES2016' --strict main.ts
    Strict mode: disabled
      ✓ tsc --module 'AMD' --experimentalDecorators --target 'ES2016'  main.ts
  Building for ES2017
    Strict mode: enabled
      ✖ tsc --module 'AMD' --experimentalDecorators --target 'ES2017' --strict main.ts
    Strict mode: disabled
      ✓ tsc --module 'AMD' --experimentalDecorators --target 'ES2017'  main.ts
Testing module generation: System
  Building for ES5
    Strict mode: enabled
      ✖ tsc --module 'System' --experimentalDecorators --target 'ES5' --strict main.ts
    Strict mode: disabled
      ✓ tsc --module 'System' --experimentalDecorators --target 'ES5'  main.ts
  Building for ES2015
    Strict mode: enabled
      ✖ tsc --module 'System' --experimentalDecorators --target 'ES2015' --strict main.ts
    Strict mode: disabled
      ✓ tsc --module 'System' --experimentalDecorators --target 'ES2015'  main.ts
  Building for ES2016
    Strict mode: enabled
      ✖ tsc --module 'System' --experimentalDecorators --target 'ES2016' --strict main.ts
    Strict mode: disabled
      ✓ tsc --module 'System' --experimentalDecorators --target 'ES2016'  main.ts
  Building for ES2017
    Strict mode: enabled
      ✖ tsc --module 'System' --experimentalDecorators --target 'ES2017' --strict main.ts
    Strict mode: disabled
      ✓ tsc --module 'System' --experimentalDecorators --target 'ES2017'  main.ts
Testing module generation: UMD
  Building for ES5
    Strict mode: enabled
      ✖ tsc --module 'UMD' --experimentalDecorators --target 'ES5' --strict main.ts
    Strict mode: disabled
      ✓ tsc --module 'UMD' --experimentalDecorators --target 'ES5'  main.ts
  Building for ES2015
    Strict mode: enabled
      ✖ tsc --module 'UMD' --experimentalDecorators --target 'ES2015' --strict main.ts
    Strict mode: disabled
      ✓ tsc --module 'UMD' --experimentalDecorators --target 'ES2015'  main.ts
  Building for ES2016
    Strict mode: enabled
      ✖ tsc --module 'UMD' --experimentalDecorators --target 'ES2016' --strict main.ts
    Strict mode: disabled
      ✓ tsc --module 'UMD' --experimentalDecorators --target 'ES2016'  main.ts
  Building for ES2017
    Strict mode: enabled
      ✖ tsc --module 'UMD' --experimentalDecorators --target 'ES2017' --strict main.ts
    Strict mode: disabled
      ✓ tsc --module 'UMD' --experimentalDecorators --target 'ES2017'  main.ts
Testing module generation: ES6
  Building for ES5
    Strict mode: enabled
      ✖ tsc --module 'ES6' --experimentalDecorators --target 'ES5' --strict main.ts
    Strict mode: disabled
      ✓ tsc --module 'ES6' --experimentalDecorators --target 'ES5'  main.ts
  Building for ES2015
    Strict mode: enabled
      ✖ tsc --module 'ES6' --experimentalDecorators --target 'ES2015' --strict main.ts
    Strict mode: disabled
      ✓ tsc --module 'ES6' --experimentalDecorators --target 'ES2015'  main.ts
  Building for ES2016
    Strict mode: enabled
      ✖ tsc --module 'ES6' --experimentalDecorators --target 'ES2016' --strict main.ts
    Strict mode: disabled
      ✓ tsc --module 'ES6' --experimentalDecorators --target 'ES2016'  main.ts
  Building for ES2017
    Strict mode: enabled
      ✖ tsc --module 'ES6' --experimentalDecorators --target 'ES2017' --strict main.ts
    Strict mode: disabled
      ✓ tsc --module 'ES6' --experimentalDecorators --target 'ES2017'  main.ts
Testing module generation: ES2015
  Building for ES5
    Strict mode: enabled
      ✖ tsc --module 'ES2015' --experimentalDecorators --target 'ES5' --strict main.ts
    Strict mode: disabled
      ✓ tsc --module 'ES2015' --experimentalDecorators --target 'ES5'  main.ts
  Building for ES2015
    Strict mode: enabled
      ✖ tsc --module 'ES2015' --experimentalDecorators --target 'ES2015' --strict main.ts
    Strict mode: disabled
      ✓ tsc --module 'ES2015' --experimentalDecorators --target 'ES2015'  main.ts
  Building for ES2016
    Strict mode: enabled
      ✖ tsc --module 'ES2015' --experimentalDecorators --target 'ES2016' --strict main.ts
    Strict mode: disabled
      ✓ tsc --module 'ES2015' --experimentalDecorators --target 'ES2016'  main.ts
  Building for ES2017
    Strict mode: enabled
      ✖ tsc --module 'ES2015' --experimentalDecorators --target 'ES2017' --strict main.ts
    Strict mode: disabled
      ✓ tsc --module 'ES2015' --experimentalDecorators --target 'ES2017'  main.ts
Testing module generation: ESNext
  Building for ES5
    Strict mode: enabled
      ✖ tsc --module 'ESNext' --experimentalDecorators --target 'ES5' --strict main.ts
    Strict mode: disabled
      ✓ tsc --module 'ESNext' --experimentalDecorators --target 'ES5'  main.ts
  Building for ES2015
    Strict mode: enabled
      ✖ tsc --module 'ESNext' --experimentalDecorators --target 'ES2015' --strict main.ts
    Strict mode: disabled
      ✓ tsc --module 'ESNext' --experimentalDecorators --target 'ES2015'  main.ts
  Building for ES2016
    Strict mode: enabled
      ✖ tsc --module 'ESNext' --experimentalDecorators --target 'ES2016' --strict main.ts
    Strict mode: disabled
      ✓ tsc --module 'ESNext' --experimentalDecorators --target 'ES2016'  main.ts
  Building for ES2017
    Strict mode: enabled
      ✖ tsc --module 'ESNext' --experimentalDecorators --target 'ES2017' --strict main.ts
    Strict mode: disabled
      ✓ tsc --module 'ESNext' --experimentalDecorators --target 'ES2017'  main.ts
```

### Solid `tsconfig`

Based on those results, it looks like this is an okay `tsconfig`.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "<not None>",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "strict": false
  }
}
```

### Final Notes

- I didn't test as many compiler options as I could have. If there's interest, I can update the repo later.
- I still don't have a good answer for OP's issue and that bothers me.
- I did check TS version as well. [OP was using `2.4.2`](https://github.com/menehune23/local-motive/blob/eb3f2097bd00b63fa7a7e4ad1c03714da0c2e2e2/package.json#L52) and [I'm using `2.7.2`](https://github.com/thecjharries/typescript-strict-demo/blob/74e2c311593ef038ac147e540a2487dc0bcaa776/package.json#L5). Just to make sure that wasn't the issue, [I bumped my version down too](https://travis-ci.org/thecjharries/typescript-strict-demo/builds/348945460).

Comment: Thanks for the investigation. I don't believe there's an extra config getting in the way. You can see that I do indeed have automated tests that ran and passed for the latest commit (https://travis-ci.org/menehune23/local-motive/builds/277173444). Travis calls my `test` npm script for me.

Answer (score 0):

'this' is undefined because you are not properly configuring the property descriptor.

Instead of:

```
Object.defineProperty(target, key, {
      get: getter,
      set: setter,
      enumerable: true,
      configurable: true
    });
```

Do something like:

```
Object.defineProperty(target, key, {
      get() {
         // this is defined
      },
      set(value: any) {
         // this is defined
      },
      enumerable: true,
      configurable: true
    });
```

I had the same issue and the solution above solves it.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

instead of

```js
function logProperty(target: any, key: string) {

 ...
}
```

using:

```
const logProperty = (target: any, key: string) => {
 ...
}
```

because `=>` 's `this` just outside, so it can get it.
hope it's helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I used allen wang post to build from and came up with this

```
export const logProperty = (target: any, key: string) => {
    let val = this?[key]: '';

    const getter = () => {
        console.log(`Get: ${key} => ${val}`);
        return val;
    };

    const setter = (newVal) => {
        console.log(`Set: ${key} => ${newVal}`);
        val = newVal;
    };

    if (val) {
        Object.defineProperty(target, key, {
            get: getter,
            set: setter,
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: true
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I met the similar issue but w/ a serial strict conditions.

My code was like below:

```js
namespace StringUtil {
  export function validate(...) {...} 
}

export function mv_string(minLen: number, maxLen: number, allowNull?: boolean, errCode?: string, errMsg?: string) {
    return function (target: any, propertyKey: string) {
        let cls = target.constructor as Function;
        createValidator(cls, propertyKey, StringUtil.validate, [minLen, maxLen, allowNull], errCode, errMsg);
    };
}

class MyCls {
    @mv_string
    myProp: string;
}
```

Previously I was using typescript 3.7.0+ w/ a lower ts-node version, all goes fine no matter running via ts-node or via webpack && node xxx.

Later I upgrade to typescript 4.7.0+ w/ a ts-node 10.0.0+ version, the webpack & node run goes fine as well, however ts-node | ts-node-dev give a runtime issue:

```
/Users/xxx/xxx/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js:553
                var decorated = decorator(target, propertyKey, descriptor);
                                ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'validate')
    at /Users/xxx/xxx/src/xxx/my-xxx-validator.ts:55:54
    at DecorateProperty (/Users/xxx/xxx/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js:553:33)
    at Reflect.decorate (/Users/xxx/xxx/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js:123:24)
    at __decorate (/Users/xxx/xxx/src/my-xxx-tscode.ts:4:92)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/xxx/xxx/src/my-xxx-tscode.ts:6:5)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Module.m._compile (/Users/xxx/xxx/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:839:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/Users/xxx/xxx/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:842:12)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
```

It major said `StringUtil` is undefined when using `StringUtil.validate` as I could see.

I doubt the reason might like @CJ Harries mentioned above but I'm not sure, playing w/ typescript it looks namespace would be compiled as an object so it's wired... Maybe the upgrade caused any break change when on decorator while via ts-node?