# TypeScript Decorator Issue - How to decorate methods which use "this" to access instance properties

Tags: typescript, decorator

I have an issue where if I decorate a method, if the method is accessing properties of the instance they are undefined. I found somewhere here that it is a known issue because instances are not yet defined when the decorators are used. Is it even possible to decorate a method which uses "this" to access instance properties? I am using NestJS and this creates a big issue because the methods now don't see the injected services.
Example of not working code:

```js
const MethodLogger = (target: any, propertyKey: string | symbol, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) => {
    const originalMethod = descriptor.value;
    descriptor.value = async (...args: any[]) => {
        console.log(
            `${String(propertyKey)} started`,
            target.constructor.name,
        );
        const result = await originalMethod.apply(target, args);
        console.log(
            `${String(propertyKey)} finished`,
            target.constructor.name,
        );
        return result;
    };
    return descriptor;
};

class A {
    notAccessibleProperty = new B()
    propertyA = 'Test'
    aMethodNoDecorator() {
        console.log('A not decorated')
        this.aMethodDecorated()
    }

    @MethodLogger
    aMethodDecorated() {
        console.log('A decorated')
        console.log(this.propertyA)
        this.aAnotherMethod()
        this.notAccessibleProperty.bMethodNoDecorator() // this fails, I would need it to work
    }

    aAnotherMethod() {
        console.log('A Another method')
    }
}

class B {
    bMethodNoDecorator() {
        console.log('B not decorated')
    }
}

const a = new A()
a.aMethodNoDecorator()
```

The log output is:

```
A not decorated
aMethodDecorated started A
A decorated
undefined
A Another method
D:\Projects\typescript\ts-test\dist\server.js:33
        this.notAccessibleProperty.bMethodNoDecorator();
                                   ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'bMethodNoDecorator')
```

I tried multiple solutions to binding the instance to the method in the decorator as were discussed here ['this' is Undefined in TypeScript Property Decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45830878/this-is-undefined-in-typescript-property-decorator)
None worked for me.

If the method can call methods of the instance by "this" I thought it should be able to get properties of the instance.

Comment: I have an example of NestJS app [here](https://github.com/Qualatea/nestjs-test/tree/master)